# How do I add Android-EasyLocation library in a background service

Tags: java, android, service

I want to use Easylocation library in my service and want to update the location to my server periodically. Could you please help me.

https://github.com/akhgupta/Android-EasyLocation

Comment: If you are using a library for location, then try this [Smart Location Library](https://github.com/mrmans0n/smart-location-lib). you will get everything. perodic updates and much more

Comment: Does it work perfectly with Marshmallow 6.0 and above versions? I will give it a try. Thanks

Comment: Actually bro for marshmellow and up you need to ask permission before accessing location as every app do.. after that start fetching location

Comment: Thank you Abhishek for your help. I will check it now how it works.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use official solution if you need to get location.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
        ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener {
    ...
    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
        mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(
                mGoogleApiClient);
        if (mLastLocation != null) {
            mLatitudeText.setText(String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLatitude()));
            mLongitudeText.setText(String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLongitude()));
        }
    }
}
```

more info in [oficcial site](https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html)

If you need to get it inside a service consider using it inside `JobService` or `jobDispatcher` for compatibility with android O. Tell me if you need more information.